# how to set the controller to respond as plain text in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller

I need to create an API for monitoring and for that need that the response will be plain text , not json or xml

What I did is:

checked my application yaml that it contains text:

```
 types:
        all: '*/*'
        atom: application/atom+xml
        css: text/css
        csv: text/csv
        excel: application/vnd.ms-excel
        xlsx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
        form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        html:
          - text/html
          - application/xhtml+xml
        js: text/javascript
        json:
          - application/json
          - text/json
        multipartForm: multipart/form-data
        pdf: application/pdf
        rss: application/rss+xml
        text: text/plain
        hal:
          - application/hal+json
          - application/hal+xml
        xml:
          - text/xml
          - application/xml
```

added to my controller: `static responseFormats = ['all']`, tried also `static responseFormats = ['text']`

in my method did:

```
respond mystring, formats:['text']
```

But still grails trying to convert it to JSON and throwing http 406 error

How can I configure my controller to work with plain text

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out how to do it 
i used render instead of respond in my method which solved the problem, still not sure why it is not possible with respond

```
class MonitorApi4Controller {

   static responseFormats = ['text']
   static allowedMethods = [ monitorScrape: "GET"]

   MonitorService getMonitorService(){
       return ApplicationContextHolder.getBean('monitorService')
   }

   def monitorScrape(){
       def message = getMonitorService().serviceMethod()
       render message
   }
}
```